# Fastest way to copy my own system memory RGB array into a Win32 window

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, direct2d

while it seems such a basic question, I open this thread after extensive stackoverflow and Google search, which helped but not in a definitive way.

My C++ code draws to an array used as RGB framebuffer, hardware acceleration is not possible for this original graphics algorithm and I want my software to directly generate the images (no hardware acceleration) also for portability reasons.

However, I would like to have hardware acceleration to copy my C++ array into the window.

In the past, I have outputted to BMP files the images generated by my code, now I want to display them as efficiently as possible in realtime, on the screen's window.

I wrote a Win32 program that has a window freely resizeable by the user, so far so good.

What is the best / fastest / most efficient way to (possibly v-synched) blit/copy my system memory RGB array (I can adapt my graphics generator to any RGB format, so to avoid conversions) into the window that can change size any moment? (I am handling resizing via WM messages, and anyway I'm not asking how to resize/rescale the image array, I will do it all by myself, I mention resizeable window just to say that its size cannot be fixed after creation, but I will rescale it with my own code or, more precisely, I will simply reallocate the RGB array and generate a new image when the user changes the window's size)

NOTE: the image array should be allocated by my own program, but if having a system pointer will make things much more efficient (e.g. directly in video RAM) then it's ok.

Windows10 is the target OS, but at least Windows7 retro-compatibility would be better. Hardware is PC's, even low end, released in the last 5-10 years till now, so I guess all will have GDI hardware acceleration or such, like Direct2D or how is it called DirectDraw now.

NOTE: please do NOT propose the use of any library, I will have to deal directly with GDI calls, Direct2D or whatever is most efficient to do the task, but without using third-party libraries.

Thank you very much, I don't know much about Windows GUI coding, I've done console mode only until now, and some windows (thus I am familiar with WM messages) and basic DeviceContext graphics output. From my research (but I wanted to ask here because I'm in doubt really, and lotsa post I've read date back to 2010) SetDIBitsToDevice should be the best solution to my problem, but if so I think I would still need some way to synchronize with VSynch to avoid, if possible, the annoying tearing/flickering.

Comment: *"I would still need some way to synchronize with VSynch"* - You do not. That part is handled for you by the compositor already. You're not actually writing to the screen. You're writing to an off-screen surface that the compositor uses to compose the full screen representation. That out of the way, the question asked is likely not going to get you closer to a solution. You will first have to learn how the screen is actually composed to build a mental model that matches reality.

Comment: Also, GDI hardware acceleration is *very* different from Direct2D acceleration (which is layered on top of Direct3D). Neither one is called DirectDraw now. That's an ancient technology, introduced in Windows Mobile 5.0 (that's 2005).

Comment: With the DirectX/Direct2D route (not GDI/GDI+) with recent Windows (8+), you can use flip models: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/for-best-performance--use-dxgi-flip-model which minimize buffer copies and can even bypass the desktop compositor (DWM), but if you need Windows 7 compat, this is not possible. With the desktop compositor you don't have any vsync issue, you'll just have to use a swapchain, copy the buffer and present. This will cause at least one CPU => GPU copy of your RGB buffer each time you want to change the screen. There's no really "fastest" way

Comment: @IInspectable DirectDraw is much older, early DirectX, 1998 or so.